# Adding to / overwriting Devise's current_user method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, devise, helper

I've got a User model, that has an associated keyholder and guest. To make my code more DRY, I'd like it so that current_user will refer to:
a) If a user is signed in, it will be the normal Devise current_user object.
b) If a keyholder is signed in, it will be that keyholder's user - i.e. current_keyholder.user
c) If a guest is signed in, it will be the guest's user.

I've tried adding helpers into the application controller, however, these don't work as the e.g. current_user isn't being initialized before my code runs.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
  def current_user
    if user_signed_in?
      @current_user ||= warden.authenticate(:scope => :user)
    elsif keyholder_signed_in?
      @current_user = current_keyholder.user
    elsif guest_signed_in?
      @current_user = current_guest.user
    end
  end
```

The above code gives me a "stack level too deep" error, but will hopefully show what I'm trying to get working. If anyone can help, that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround - in the application controller, I added a before_filter called access_user, then a method called access_user:

```
  def access_user
    if user_signed_in?
      @access_user = current_user
    elsif keyholder_signed_in?
      @access_user = current_keyholder.user
    elsif guest_signed_in?
      @access_user = current_guest.user
    end
  end
```

Which I can then call in the views using e.g. `<%= @access_user.id %>`

If there is a better way or this is going to cause some security issue, please can somebody let me know?